# How to get filereadable to recognize spaces in filenames/paths

Tags: vimscript

I'm trying to figure out what format to use to get filereadable to recognize a file with a space in the name.  This is in Ubuntu using version 7.4.1689.

The following all return 0:

<strike>filereadable('/home/user/file name')</strike>

```
filereadable('/home/user/file\ name')
filereadable("/home/user/file\ name")
filereadable("\/home\/user\/file\ name")
filereadable(fnameescape('/home/user/file name'))
```

How can I get filereadable to recognize a space in the path on Linux systems?

Comment: Are you really sure that `/home/user/file name` file exists and is readable?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.  If I remove the space from the path, it works fine.

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't have to use escaping of file names for filereadable. And it works well for me. I've tested this with ubuntu 16.04 and vim 7.4.1683 as you did

Comment: Like @mymedia says, `filereadable()` doesn't expect you to do any kind of escaping.  It takes a single argument and spaces don't matter.  Confirm that you're actually dealing with a space with `:echo glob('/home/user/* *')` and confirm that you're not actually seeing a non-breaking space with `:echo glob("/home/user/*\u00a0*")`

Comment: I'm seeing it now-- That definitely made a difference, and I'm not sure at the moment how that one got past me the first time (because I had it incorrectly listed as one that didn't work).

Comment: To make it clear: the first version works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filereadable('/home/user/file name')` is the correct syntax.

If you want to use wildcards as well you should use `glob`:

```
if glob('~/file name')!=#""
```

`glob` returns the full name if the file exists or `""` if it does not.